# How to hide prev arrow on first item, next arrow on last item, and both arrow if single item: angular based project; no jquery?

Tags: angular, sass, bootstrap-5

It is a template file where I wish to implement: hiding prev arrow on first item, next arrow on last item, and both arrow if single item. I have used bootstrap carousel in angular 12 version.

```
//html code
<div id="carouselExampleControls" *ngIf="selectedMusic?.type==='image'" class="carousel slide" data-bs-touch="false" data-bs-interval="false" data-bs-wrap=false>
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                          <div class="carousel-item" [ngClass] = "{ active: selectedMusic.src === data, first: first, last: last}" *ngFor="let data of carouselAsset; let first = first; let last = last" >
                            
                            <img *ngIf="selectedMusic?.type==='image'" [src]="data">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <button  class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
```

The carouselAsset used in the template file, is the collection of image file only after the filter operation achieved on the package module on other file.

```
//ts code
      // For carouselAsset
      this.carouselAsset = this.packageDetails.assets.filter(item=>item.fileType==="Images")[0].files.map(itemUrl=>itemUrl.previewUrl);
```

Comment: should be a css question imho, also I don't see any angular code

Comment: I just wished to know the implementation; the item in the caraousel item, are looped using *ngFor and the array for the looping section is retrieved from the ts file of angular.

Comment: Only way I can think of doing it is with :first() and :last() css selectors. you need to override the carousel css on arrows that are children of **:first()** and **:last() carousel-item**. this will also handle the single slide case.

Comment: To give an effective answer, I need to see your javascript code. And, it would be very nice to see a screenshot of your rendered DOM.

Comment: @cooskun I have added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from de documentation [control via javascript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/#events)

> Bootstrap’s carousel class exposes two events for hooking into
> carousel functionality. Both events have the following additional
> properties:
>
> ```
> direction: The direction in which the carousel is sliding (either "left" or "right").
> relatedTarget: The DOM element that is being slid into place as the active item.
> from: The index of the current item
> to: The index of the next item
> ```
>
> All carousel events are fired at the carousel itself (i.e. at the ). Event type    Description slide.bs.carousel   Fires
> immediately when the slide instance method is invoked.
> slid.bs.carousel  Fired when the carousel has completed its slide
> transition.
>
> ```
> var myCarousel = document.getElementById('myCarousel')
>
> myCarousel.addEventListener('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
>   // do something...
> })
> ```

We know now that it's possible control when the carousel when change. But in Angular we don't usually use docuemnt.getElementById else a template reference variable and Viewchild. Also it's better use fromEvent rxjs operator than addEventListener. So first we are going to give template reference variable to our elements

```
<div #carousel id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide"..>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div #item *ngFor="let carousel of carousels; class="carousel-item">
             ....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See the two references variables `carousel` and `item`

The idea is create an observable in ngOnInit to know the "active carousel", so, in ngOnInit

```
  @ViewChildren('item') items:QueryList<ElementRef>
  @ViewChild('carousel',{static:true}) carousel!:ElementRef

  change$:any //<--our observable

  ngOnInit(){
    //enclosed under a setTimeout to give Angular time to
    //give value to "items" and "carousel"
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.items.first.nativeElement.classList.add("active")
      this.change$=fromEvent(this.carousel.nativeElement,'slide.bs.carousel').pipe(
         startWith({to:0}),
         map((res:any)=>res.to))
    })
  }
```

See that if we write in our .html some like

```
Actual slider: {{change$|async}}
```

We are going to see how goes to 0 to imagenes length-1

Well, we can use this, remove the line before and put the buttons under a ng-container

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{ item: change$ | async } as actual">
  <button
    *ngIf="actual.item != 0"
    class="carousel-control-prev"
    ...
  >
    ...
  </button>
  <button
    *ngIf="actual.item < carousels.length - 1"
    class="carousel-control-next"
    ...
  >
    ...
  </button>
</ng-container>
```

(*) the use of the construction `*ngIf="{prop:observable|async} as variable` is very common and makes that the variable get's the value `{prop:0}` `{prop:1}`... etc. This makes not necessary makes two subscription to the observable.

A [stackbliltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2unc5k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)