# Angular using carousel with *ngfor

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5, ngfor

I am trying  to make a carousel.
This carousel image gets its imagepath string from a string array.
when i click left or right arrow I want it to increase or decrease index, so i can change image which is shown.
how can i mak this happen.
NO ts code allowed, only html can be used.

```
 <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">               
        <ul  *ngFor="let carImagePath of carImagePaths; let i= index;first as isFirst">
          <div [ngClass]="isFirst ? 'carousel-item active' : 'carousel-item' "> 
            <li><img [src]="imageUrl+carImagePath" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."></li> 
          </div>
        </ul> 
        </div>
          <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
          </button>
          <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
          </button>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Has you included in angular.json the `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js`? has you include in your package.json `"@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",`, `"@types/bootstrap": "^5.0.17"` and `"bootstrap": "^5.0.2",`? Html by self has do nothing, only static view. see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68081166/bootstrap-5-in-angular-application/68082635#68082635) to include bootstrap 5 in your angular app

Comment: It wasnt. Bu now i installed popper and types. But still nothing happens. Arrows doesnt work, i cant change photos.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71194425/how-to-hide-prev-arrow-on-first-item-next-arrow-on-last-item-and-both-arrow-if/71208621#71208621) you have a bootstrap 5 carousel, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70402216/custom-animated-image-slider-in-angular/70403362#70403362) another with animations Angular, [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples) ng-bootstrap carousel and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70496066/rotating-psuedo-3d-carousel-in-angular/70533908#70533908) a pseudo 3D carousel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution i gave up trying to use normal bootstrap carousel. I tried angular bootstrap carousel. ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component carousel . intallled this to terminal. and used it own html from via this site:
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/carousel?tab=overview

Now it is working.